# How to add a hole into passed polygon?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

I use the common source and vector layer to draw polygon and cutouts inside polygons:

```
public features: any[] = [];

  addHole(type = "Polygon", feature: Feature) {
    const modify = new Modify({ source: this.source });
    this.mapService.map.addInteraction(modify);

    const draw = new Draw({
      source: this.source,
      type: "Polygon",
    });

    draw.on("drawend", (e) => {
      this.features.push(e.feature);
      const findPolygonIndex = this.features.findIndex((f) => f == feature);
      const index = this.features.length - 1;
      const coordinates = this.features[findPolygonIndex]
        .getGeometry()
        .getCoordinates(true);

      coordinates.push(
        this.features[index].getGeometry().getCoordinates(false)[0]
      );
      this.source.removeFeature(this.features[findPolygonIndex]);
      this.features[index].getGeometry().setCoordinates(coordinates);

      draw.finishDrawing();
    });

    this.mapService.map.addInteraction(draw);
    const snap = new Snap({ source: this.source });
    this.mapService.map.addInteraction(snap);
```

The function above accept a feature (main polygon where hole should be placed).

Also this function gets a last element that must be a hole.

But OL can not cutout it. Where did I make mistake?

Comment: See https://spatial-dev.guru/2022/01/22/draw-holes-in-openlayers-polygon/